# What is the correct way to update a dictionary's value when using TryGetValue?

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics

I have a dictionary of type `IDictionary<string, LoadingProgressState>`

And what I'm doing is updating a property of the dictionary's `Value` when calling some function.

```
if(CurrentFilesProgress.TryGetValue(key, out var loadingProgress))
{
    loadingProgress.DoneLoadings = doneLoadings;
    CurrentFilesProgress[key] = loadingProgress;
}
```

Am I doing this correctly? If not, what is the correct way to update a 
dictionary value's property?
Please notice that I don't want to create a new instance of `LoadingProgressState`, I only want to update it's `DoneLoadings` property.

Comment: Assuming `loadingProgress` is a reference type (judging by context) you don't have to save it again in the dictionary. You obtain the reference and then change one of its properties; you don't actually make a copy of the object.

Comment: the assignment isn't necessary; the variable loadingProgress is a reference which the dictionary and your local variable both share. So when you changed loadingProgress.DoneLoadings, you also therefore changed CurrentFilesProgress[key], since they are the same variable.

Comment: So just remove `CurrentFilesProgress[key] = loadingProgress;` and it's good?

Comment: Yeah, should be good. I would suggest you doing some reading on reference vs. value types, is an interesting topic.

Comment: @bradbury9 I understand about reference and value types, what confused me was the `out var` which wasn't clear for me what is was doing under the hood. Thanks guys

Comment: My bad, thought your problem was with reference types. Here is the [out keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) documentation.

Comment: as long as `LoadingProgressState` is a `class`, not a `struct`: everything already said - just lose the "indexer set" line, it isn't necessary; if `LoadingProgressState` is a `struct`: use the code you already have (although: mutable structs are usually a very bad idea). Note: if this dictionary is accessed by multiple threads, you will also need synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize your code using the code below :

```
if(CurrentFilesProgress.TryGetValue(key, out var loadingProgress))
{
   loadingProgress.DoneLoadings = doneLoadings;
}
```

The reason is that the object you are handling has the same reference as the one in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the dictionary contains the key, and if so then update the property of its value like this:

```
if(CurrentFilesProgress.ContainsKey(key))
{
    CurrentFilesProgress[key].DoneLoadings = doneLoadings;
}
```